# Calculating distance between points from CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, csv, polyline-creation, length

I have a CSV-file with latitudes and longitudes and I should calculate the distance between the points in ascending order (distance from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, etc.)

I tried with the distance matrix but it calculates each point the distance with the others.

In addition, I am working in EPSG:23033 - ED50 / UTM zone 33N but when I made the distance matrix no measurement is returned. The ruler tool tells me that EPSG:7022 works automatically but I do not want to work with that CRS.

My initial CSV-file with 241rows looks like this:

[image]

I would like a new column.

Comment: You want a new table as output? Or a new column?

Comment: Can you please show us how does your csv look like ?

Comment: I would like a new column. my csv consists of 4 columns:
ID-Date-Time-Latitude.vessel-Longitude.vessel
and I have 241rows

Comment: If this is a single path, you may use the ID to convert your points to a line, then split the line by the points and calculate the length of each segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load you points to the project as described in step 1 of the solution by @Taras.

You can then automatically calculate the length you want without first reprojecting the points - this is done inside the expression with the `transform` function:

```
length (
    transform (
        make_line ( 
            geometry ( get_feature_by_id ( @layer, $id )),
            geometry ( get_feature_by_id ( @layer, $id+1 ))
        ),
    'EPSG:4326',
    'EPSG:23033'
    )
)
```

You can use this expression e.g. to set a dynamic label. If you want to create a new field, you must first save the layer in antother format (Geopackage, ShapeFile) as QGIS can't edit CSV files. If you reproject the layer during saving (see step 2 in the answer by @Taras), delete the `transform ()` part of the expression (lines 2, 7 to 9 plus the `,` on line 6). If you leave the layer in `EPSG:4326`, use the expression exactly as stated above to get length values measured in `EPSG:23033`.

When you have the layer as Geopackage, use the expression with field calculator to create the new field.

When `id + 1` exceeds the last number of a point feature, the result is a `NULL` value (no data): that is correct as the last point does not have a next point the measure a length.

*Screenshot: as you see, the layer is a csv in `EPSG:4326`, the project is in `EPSG:23033`. Each point has a label that is dynamically generated by the expression above (plus a `round` function to get rid of decimals) that calculates the distance to the next point. The line between the points is also created dynamically with geometry generator, based on the same expression:*

[image]

Comment: What happens when `id + 1` exceeds the last number of a point feature?!

Comment: It creates a `NULL` value. Updated the answer accordingly, with screenshot.

Comment: You can define a custom value like `0` for the last point by adding this part at the beginning of the expression: `if ( $id = count ( $id) +1, 0 , ` and an additional `)` at the very end.

Comment: thank you very much it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

I assume that @Erik will agree with these basic steps:

1. Import CSV into QGIS, via `Layer > Add layer > Add delimited text layer...` using the EPSG:4326
2. Reproject your layer, e.g. use `Export > Save features as...` with the *EPSG:23033* for *'CRS'* (because your original layer seems to be in *EPSG:4326*). To avoid this step, see step 5.
3. Apply the ['Points to path'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) to your imported point layer, use `"ID"` as the *'Order field'*.
4. Run the ['Explode lines'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#explode-lines) to split lines into linestrings
5. In the Attribute table calculate linestring's length using the [`$length`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#length). Otherwise try the [`transform()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#translate) function, i.e. `length(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:23033'))`. This step was described by @Babel in his answer.
6. For getting back values from the original point layer, practise witchcraft with [*joins*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html?highlight=join). Mind that there will be one-to-many connections because one linestring is a connection between two points.

Comment: Thanks, all works correct but the the unit of measurement is meters but the distances I get are wrong as if it did not measure in my sr

Comment: I need to see your data, can you share a piece of it ?