# Converting CSV file with local coordinates for project area to UTM zone 29N using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a csv file with local coordinates for a project area and want to convert to UTM zone 29N.

How do I do it with QGIS?

The files plot outside the project area, when imported into QGIS, (X-5022.867, Y-7259.176, Z-242.878) CRS is EPSG
:32629.

Comment: See here how to load points from a CSV and reprojecting them, using QGIS expressions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/391112/88814

Comment: First step, you are going to need the conversion factors from local grid to UTM Zone 29. As a minimum, you will need 3 common points with coordinates in both systems or the equation to transform local to UTM. Perhaps check with the source of the data.